# Search result by range?

Tags: search

I have to search for posts that have in tags or custom fields a number(price): example 152. Each post have a price tag. How I do to search for all post greater than a price for example I need to search for all post who have a price tag of minimum 100.

Something like /?s=keyword&price>=300

Thx

Answer (score 4):

If the price is stored as a custom field you'll need to use the `meta_query` argument of `WP_Query` ([see Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)). For instance:

```
 //Get posts with custom field 'price' between 20 and 100
 $price_filtered = WP_Query(array(
     'meta_query'=>array(
         array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
         ),
      )
 ));
```

(where `price` is the key of the custom field). Depending on how you might be implementing this (is it intended to be the 'main query' or not - [you might want to use this at `pre_get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762))

#### Edit

If filtering a search result:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse71814_filter_search');
function wpse71814_filter_search( $query ){
     if( $query->is_search() && isset($_GET['min']) ){

         //Collect user input from $_GET for example
         $user_input_min_value = $_GET['min'];

         $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

         $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $user_input_min_value,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '>='
         );

         $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
      }
}
```

**Note:** The original answer had a meta query which specified a range. The second answer has a meta query which filters for prices above some minimum value.

**Usage:** `/?s=keyword&min=300`

Comment: Ok nice, but the search value need to be custom because the website user must put his own minimum value for price search

Comment: So will be great if I can use that minimum value(price) in url search.

Comment: Something like /?s=keyword&price>=300

Answer (score 4):

If you save the the price in a meta field, you can query posts using `meta_query`:

```
<?php
    $the_posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'meta_key' => 'price',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => '100',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
    ));
?>
<?php while ( $the_posts->have_posts() ) : $the_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Ok nice, but the search value need to be custom because the website user must put his own minimum value for price search

Comment: So will be great if I can use that minimum value(price) in url search

Comment: Something like /?s=keyword&price>=300